# Pool readers and streams with Json.NET

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

This code is built on Json.NET and gets called hundreds of times per second. My data starts in an `ArraySegment<byte>`. I wrap that in a `MemoryStream` and pass it in to the code. It's generally small data: hundreds of bytes, not thousands. It just doesn't seem right that I have to construct multiple streams and readers for every single deserialization call. How do I optimize this? How do I reuse those two readers?

```
public object Deserialize(Stream stream, Type type)
{
    using (var utfReader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8, true, 2048, true))
    using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(utfReader) { CloseInput = false })
        return _serializer.Deserialize(reader, type);
}

public T Deserialize<T>(Stream stream)
{
    return (T)Deserialize(stream, typeof(T));
}
```

Comment: You don't show us the code that calls this, so what do you expect us to do? There aren't even a dozen lines, I don't see anything we can review.

Answer (score 2):

You could create your own `TextReader` that allows you to change the underlying `Stream`, or even directly reads from the `ArraySegment<byte>`.

But hundreds of times per second is not that often, are you sure worrying about allocations here is worth it? And if it is, I would first look at the 2 kB of buffer your `StreamReader` allocates every time it's created, rather than the few tens of bytes for the `StreamReader` and `JsonTextReader` objects.